# coercivity of a bilinear form

Tags: finite-element, discontinuous-galerkin, elliptic-pde

Consider a bi-linear form
$a(u,v) = \int_\Omega A\nabla u \cdot  \nabla v - \sum_e \int_e${$\nabla u$} $ \cdot [A u]$

defined on a discrete polynomial space $V_h \subset H^1_0(\Omega)$ with {.} and [.] are the mean and jump which are well defined on the interface $e$, and $A$ is an elliptic and piecewise constant matrix. Is it true that $a(u,u) \ge C \lVert \nabla u \rVert^2 _{L^2(\Omega)}$ ?

Comment: Did you consider a simple case where $A$ is a scalar function and the domain $\Omega$ is a square?

Comment: No, I haven't. How should I proceed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On the space $V_h$ you describe, namely a subspace of $H^1_0$, this is trivially true. This is because functions in $H^1_0$ are continuous except perhaps on subsets of dimension $d-2$. As a consequence, $[Au]=A[u]=0$ in $L_2(e)$ because $e$ is $d-1$ dimensional. What remains of your bilinear form is then only the first term, which of course satisfies the stated inequality with $C$ equal to the smallest eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: A is piecewise constant with respect to the triangulation, so the last term $[Au]=[A]u$ doesn't disappear actually.

Comment: Ah, I missed that :-(